# Building on M1, error Could not find module ... for target x86_64-apple-ios-simulator

Tags: swift, apple-m1, swift-package-manager, apple-silicon, xcode12.5

Attempting to build project with Swift module. Xcode 12.5.1. Builds fine on Intel machine.
Builds fine on M1 machine if building for iOS device.
Does not build on M1 machine if building for simulator.

Error: Could not find module xxx for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator

There are several pods also being used. Some report building for x86_64. I don't understand why. In particular `flurry`.

When it gets to our Swift module xxx its importing, it generates the above error.

I have tried setting `Build Active Architecture Only` both Yes and No.
I have tried overriding in Podfile as well.
I have tried adding x86 to list of `Architectures`.

What tells Xcode to attempt to build x86 architecture? This is on an M1 machine. There should be no need for x86.

Thanks

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I have not solved it yet. I'm currently working on it. I had several issues. I think a Flurry update may have resolved that one, but we have a Swift package we've developed locally behaving the same way. I'm investigating how that Swift package is created.

Comment: Turns out our Swift package is not the issue. The issue appears to be use of Flurry iOS SDK. It does not appear fixed yet. There is a discussion that indicates what Flurry needs to do. https://github.com/flurry/flurry-ios-sdk/issues/207#issuecomment-777674498